# how to import typescript in an existing vue 2 program

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I wanner import typescript  in an existing vue 2 program, based on javascript.
I want to do development incrementally instead of doing most change.
Do bosses have any solutions?

Comment: We’d love to help you, but your question lacks information and clarity.  To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Vue has built-in typescript support, so you can get started by just creating a tsconfig file and changing main.js to `main.ts`. No usual @types/... definitions are needed.

See this git repository for details on how to set everything up (from Vue >2.6) https://github.com/AvocadoVenom/typescript-me

Comment: I have tried, but it changed 2 much. I do not wanner do this.